# Is JSch SSH session channel a separate TCP connection?

Tags: ssh, tcp, sftp, jsch

I have some files to be uploaded to an SFTP server, so I use JSch to accomplish this goal.

I have these options for implementation:

1. JSch opens one session and one channel
2. JSch opens one session and multiple channels

The above two solutions, which is more efficient?

Does one session correspond to a TCP connection, or does one channel correspond to a TCP connection?

If one session corresponds to a TCP connection, then multiple channels must share the same TCP connection, can it be more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One SSH session corresponds to one TCP connection. A channel is just a virtual "connection" within the one SSH/TCP connection.

As you have rightly assumed, it can hardly be more efficient to use multiple channels.

Option to use multiple channels is not for efficiency, but for flexibility (imo).

---

Actually using multiple channels can be less efficient.

It depends on how efficiently the SSH parties implement an SSH flow control (sliding window), comparing to efficiency of a TCP flow control (which will usually be super-optimized).

Some SFTP clients, when they know that only one channel will be opened, deliberately set client-side SSH window to a huge number, to leave the flow control to TCP (expecting it to be more efficient).

Also, PuTTY-based SFTP clients (like psftp or WinSCP) announce to the server that it will only ever use one channel (using a proprietary `simple@putty.projects.tartarus.org` message), so that the server can also opt to leave flow control to TCP too. Not that I know of any SSH server to actually take advantage of this.